Can the applied force be greater than electric force? Why is the applied force considered to be equal to electric force?
If the applied force is greater than that of electric force, will the work done by applied force formula still hold? Why is the potential energy negative of work done by electric force? Why can't it be same?

Hi Susan, for someone to answer your question, you'll need to describe the scenario you're thinking of, especially what applied force you mean.

I suspect that your questions on this subject originate from a particular definition of electrostatic potential energy in terms of the work done by a different force. Am I wrong? If this is the case, it would be better to include that definition to help people tune the answer to your conceptual needs.


If the applied force is greater than that of electric force , will the
work done by applied force formula still hold?

The work done by any force depends only on that force and the displacement resulting from the point of application of that force, regardless of the presence of other forces. However, the net work done will be determined by displacement due the net force of all forces involved.

Why is the potential energy negative of work done by electric force? Why can't it be the same.

Because any work done by a conservative force (of which electrical is one), must result in a decrease or increase in potential energy, depending on whether the conservative force does positive or negative work, respectively.
If a conservative force does positive work, it transfers energy to that something at the expense of (decrease in) potential energy. If the conservative force does negative work, it takes energy away from something and stores it as (causes an increase in) potential energy.
Hope this helps.
